# Linq to Entities how to lock reads

Tags: linq-to-entities

I'm wondering if it's possible to lock a table while I read and write to it so noone else is able to read from that table until I'm done with what I'm doing. 
So I don't run into this problem:

I read a value from table

Someone else read a value from the same table

I make an insert that should only be possible because of the read I did.

Someone else now tries to make an insert that he shouldn't have come to the conclusion was possible because he shouldn't  have been able to read before I was done with my insert.

Now there's 2 rows in the table that shouldn't be able to be there at the same time.

How do I solve this if locking reads isn't possible? I tried using CHECK but couldn't do it because I wasn't allowed to make a select in my CHECK.

Comment: I don't remember what the default transaction isolation level is (and the default changed in EF6) but you probably want to set transaction level to COMMITTED (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) and then do the operations inside a transaction

Comment: The best way to prevent duplicates is a unique index and exception handling. Pessimistic locking isn't recommended in most cases.

Comment: Committed only makes me unable to read data that is being modified, but all the rows that are in the table already aren't being modified, so that won't help. I understand that Pessimistic locking might not be recommended, but is it possible to do? It doesn't have anything to do with duplicates. It's a booking system with times that can't overlap because I would get a double booking which I'm not interrested in.

Comment: Serialization might be what I'm looking for. But it says "No other transactions can modify data that has been read by the current transaction until the current transaction completes." Does a read count as a Modify? Because if not then even the highest isolation lvl doesn't solve my problem. Then I'd have to Lock the table for reads entirely? And I'm not sure you can do that?